# Not able to see the Text after doing some pre-procssing in "tm" package

Tags: tm

```
corpus = tm_map(corpus,tolower)
corpus = tm_map(corpus,PlainTextDocument) corpus[[1]]
```

I was expecting the tweet text in lowercase,instead its showing the below:

```
<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 101
```